# Exception is thrown when input with % is send to the back end - Thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, character-encoding, thymeleaf

I have some html text inputs which send data to a back-end spring system. When I put just a (%) as a character I am getting the following Exception:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Incomplete escaping sequence in input
14:17:34,269 INFO  [stdout] (default task-4)    at org.unbescape.uri.UriEscapeUtil.unescape(UriEscapeUtil.java:617)
14:17:34,269 INFO  [stdout] (default task-4)    at org.unbescape.uri.UriEscape.unescapeUriQueryParam(UriEscape.java:1702)
14:17:34,269 INFO  [stdout] (default task-4)    at org.unbescape.uri.UriEscape.unescapeUriQueryParam(UriEscape.java:1668)
14:17:34,269 INFO  [stdout] (default task-4)    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.SpringRequestUtils.checkViewNameNotInRequest(SpringRequestUtils.java:55)
14:17:34,269 INFO  [stdout] (default task-4)    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:275)
14:17:34,269 INFO  [stdout] (default task-4)    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190)
```

I am encoding the data before is sent to the back-end using JS's encodeURIComponent method and in the link the % becomes %25 which is the correct encoded value but why does it throw an exception and what is the possible solution to this I am out of ideas tbh.

Thank you in advance for your responses :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not disclose more information other than "When I put just a (%) as a character" and "I am encoding the data".

My crystal bulb is telling me there is some http(s) request and one of the request parameters contains an encoded percentage sign only. When this request is parsed by the server the %25 is decoded back into %. So far no problem.

But is it possible that the application now tries to decode the data itself and just sees the % sign? Then it would come back with exactly the error that you see.

In that case you might want to double encode: % -> %25 -> %2525

Comment: I am sorry If I phrased it poorly. So I have 5 input texts, those input texts are corresponding fields to a FilterDto that is used to filter the data based on their values. Now when I insert a % in any of the text fields and a request is sent to the back-end I receive this exception.

Before the data is sent to the back-end is encoded using the encodeURIComponent method. Isn't double encoding going to cause a problem with my URL? Those input text values are present in the page's URL (in their encoded format)

Comment: So I guessed correctly about the characters showing up in some URL. What happens if you double-encode the value?

Comment: You were correct double encoding and decoding worked except of the GetMapping (where the url values are sent to the back-end partly encoded) part where the value needed to be decoded once (because the browser automatically does the initial decoding). Sadly this is a Thymeleaf bug which I hope to be fixed: 

https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring/issues/255

Answer (score 0):

change your thymeleaf version.

```
<properties>
    <thymeleaf.version>3.0.13.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
</properties>
```

for more information about this bug, you can read about it. hope it will resolve your issue.[Thymeleaf Issue#255]
[1]: https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring/issues/255

Comment: I managed to fix this issue back then by converting the payload to JSON and so bypassing the whole thymeleaf problem. But thanks for your answer :)